# React JS (not native) is there a way to create an external timer to force log out a user even after the window is closed?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Right now, I am using the react-idle-timer library to log a user out after a period of inactivity. However, when I close all tabs or windows associated with my application and wait the idle period, then open up the webapp again, I am still considered an active user. I want to find a way to log a user out if they close the webapps after a certain period of time.

I tried using react-native AppState, but I started my app with create-react-app and I am having issues getting the application to react native.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your user closes the browser tabs/window, it is like they are killing a process using the task manager: The application has no running instances anymore and there is no possibility to prevent this from happening. Therefore, it is not possible to achieve such a log-out mechanism *using a client-side approach.*

However, there are some possible solutions to this requirement to log out a user upon inactivity, which highly depend on the authentication mechanisms you use.

- If your app is frontend-only (and has no dependencies to any backend services), you can have a „last active“ timestamp in local storage, compare and update it on each action and invalidate the users credentials if necessary.
- For session-based log-in, you can make the session expire when the user closes the window (which should be the default behavior). Additionally, you can add a session variable similar to the „last active“ field, which is updated on each action and invalidates the authentication state from server side if necessary.
- If you are using token-based authentication, you can tweak the token expiration period and regularly re-issue a new token (probably not best practice, but might be working…)

In general, in terms of security, you should always prefer relying on information saved on the server-side of your app rather than on the client-side. Information in the browser can be easily manipulated by an attacker, while checking for a forced log out on the server-side even works when the user decides to hard-reset their machine (or experiences a power outage, …). And if your server-side is not working anymore one day… well, then you have some bigger problems.

Regarding `react` and `react-native`, though they are working pretty much the same and are using the same framework paradigms, they have one major difference: They are compiling for different platforms. Therefore from my experience and from their technical foundation, it is neither easy nor recommended to use components of one of them for the other one. So it highly depends on your use case which of them to use best.

Even though this is not a safe & sound solution, I hope to give you some orientation on your possibilities for such a log out.

Comment: We are doing server side rendering where a user sends their JWT with a 5 minute expiration to our backend, which checks that the JWT is valid before returning any data. I am using AWS Cognito to handle my sessions and log ins (I think I will look into what you suggested concerning the either a last visited timestamp or using AWS cognito and using a session that I reload whenever the user is active (not idle))

Does this still have bad security implications?